# Convergence of Expectations (cont'd)

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, self-learning, expectation

The question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018242/convergence-of-expectations).

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of indep. random variables with zero expectation. Consider their sum $S_n$ which have the following properties: $S_n$ converges a.s. to some non degenerate $S$ and

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E[\max(S_n,0)]=\infty$$

Is there exists a condition under which $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E[\max(S_n,0)]=E[\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\max(S_n,0)]$?
$\max(S_n,0)$ is not monotonic sequence so we cannot use monotone convergence theorem. Also, the reverse Fatou's lemma cannot be applied since $S_n$ is not bounded.

Thank's!

Comment: According to your assumption, the equality of limits you want will hold if and only if the random variable $\max\{S,0\}$ is not integrable.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Yes, I'm trying to show that the limiting variable  $S$ is not integrable (so, if $S^+$ has infinite expectation, I'm done) ...

Comment: Do you have some particular condition on the sequence $(X_n)$?

Comment: Actually, as an example I was thinking about truncated Cauchy. Namely, if $Y_n\sim Cauchy(0, n^{-2})$ then $X_n=Y_n 1\{Y_n\le b_n\}$ so that sum of $Y_n$'s converges and with proper choice of $b_n$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E[S_n^+]=\infty$.